# Flutter can I change languages inside dropdown widget?

Tags: flutter, localization

In sreamBuilder i call selectedLanguage from sheredPreferences. I need to call streamBuilder example in other widget. Specifically in dropDown widget and need to call method to change language globally. I use   flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter packet.
and json format for languages string.
All suggestions are welcome.

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyAppextends StatelessWidget {
  final _userPreferences = locator.get<UserPreferences>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return

      return StreamBuilder(
          stream: _userPreferences.selectedLanguageStream,
         
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return MaterialApp(
                title: 'VSC',
                navigatorKey: navigatorStateGlobalKey,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                locale: Locale(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 'en'),
                supportedLocales: languagesList
                    .map(
                      (locale) => Locale(locale.languageCode),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  Localization.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
                  for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
                    if (supportedLocale.languageCode ==
                            locale.languageCode &&
                        supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                      return supportedLocale;
                    }
                  }
                  return supportedLocales.first;
                },
                theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                    scaffoldBackgroundColor:
                        Color.fromRGBO(241, 244, 246, 1),
                    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 0,
                        actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(21, 54, 131, 1),
                        )),
                    bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
                      elevation: 0,
                      selectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(21, 54, 131, 1),
                      unselectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(127, 145, 187, 1),
                      selectedLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    )),
                home:
                     LoginPage());
          });
```

}
}

Comment: For future questions, please ensure your code is formatted correctly (i.e. using dartfmt) and as minimal as possible - the quicker it is for someone to read your code the more likely they are to help you =).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper such as Provider or Bloc.

Wrap your root widget with it and hold all language logic inside wrapper.

In code just call something like LangProvider.changeLang(language).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file containing global variables (every header, description or any kind of text that You want to be translated) and make the global variable for selected language.

Example:

```
String languageType = " "
```

You assign the value based on dropdown choice and simply when You want to translate text just assign text based on languageType.
This is the easiest approach to have multilingual application especially if You are new to Flutter.

The example down below is if you want to have two languages for example English and Bosnian language.

If you want to add more languages simply add them like we did with this format ...? ... : ..."

Example 2#:

```
String header = languageType == "english" ? "header" : "naslov"
```